# Having trouble to convert csv file to xml file using gnome libxml library in c

Tags: c, xml, csv, libxml2

When i try to convert the following csv file to xml file, i get the following xml file.I have three questions:

1. What is that weird character next to the value of student status in xml file?
2. I cannot see some csv columns in xml file.
3. I try to put 0 in xml file where a column in csv file does not have a value.How can i do that?

Note:This is a homework.

---

csv file:

```
STUDENT ID,STUDENT NAME,STUDENT SURNAME,COURSE CODE,COURSE CREDIT,MID1,MID2,HW1,HW2,HW3,FINAL,GRADE,STATUS
2015700001,Mesut,GAVGA,CME2202,3,68,74,80,75,65,70,CB,Successful
2015700001,Mesut,GAVGA,CME3004,4,36,32,0,0,,40,FF,Failed
2015700001,Mesut,GAVGA,CME2206,3,80,75,85,78,70,82,BB,Successful
2015700001,Mesut,GAVGA,CME2204,3,90,90,100,96,88,85,AA,Successful
2016700018,Merve Rana,SARI,CME2202,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,D,Absent
2016700018,Merve Rana,SARI,CME2204,3,55,57,0,66,60,48,DC,Successful
2016700018,Merve Rana,SARI,CME2206,3,60,65,70,70,63,60,CC,Successful
2015700022,Nadir,ÖZCAN,CME2202,3,98,95,98,90,92,85,AA,Successful
2015700022,Nadir,ÖZCAN,CME3004,4,85,90,88,90,,90,AA,Successful
2015700022,Nadir,ÖZCAN,CME2206,3,90,78,95,90,88,92,AA,Successful
2016700019,Mehmet Emin,TATLI,CME2204,3,20,12,0,25,0,30,FF,Failed
2016700019,Mehmet Emin,TATLI,CME2206,3,15,0,0,0,0,0,D,Absent
2015700030,Ali,SALMANLI,CME2202,3,82,77,100,98,100,68,BA,Successful
2015700030,Ali,SALMANLI,CME3004,4,76,80,80,80,,67,BB,Successful
2015700030,Ali,SALMANLI,CME3006,4,80,,70,75,,75,BB,Successful
2015700030,Ali,SALMANLI,CME2204,3,90,94,95,90,88,80,AA,Successful
2015700031,Selin,BAYTUR,CME2202,3,40,38,0,20,25,26,FF,Failed
2015700031,Selin,BAYTUR,CME3004,4,65,60,72,65,,58,CC,Successful
2015700031,Selin,BAYTUR,CME2204,3,60,48,50,52,50,60,DC,Successful
2016700020,Oğulcan,ÖZARSLAN,CME2202,3,65,80,100,100,95,85,BA,Successful
2016700020,Oğulcan,ÖZARSLAN,CME2206,3,86,88,90,90,100,100,AA,Successful
2015700042,Murat,GÜREL,CME2204,3,40,0,0,50,20,38,FF,Failed
2015700042,Murat,GÜREL,CME2202,3,71,63,65,74,70,60,CB,Successful
2016700035,Sercan,ERGÖRMÜŞ,CME3006,4,100,,100,95,,88,AA,Successful
2016700036,Çağla,PAK,CME3006,4,47,,52,60,,38,DD,Successful
2016700036,Çağla,PAK,CME2206,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,D,Absent
2016700036,Çağla,PAK,CME2204,3,8,18,0,25,50,35,FF,Failed
2016700037,Kerim,KENAR,CME2206,3,70,75,80,80,72,75,BB,Successful
2016700037,Kerim,KENAR,CME2204,3,80,80,85,56,70,48,CB,Successful
2016700050,Eda,CANSEVER,CME3006,4,45,,70,70,,94,BB,Successful
2015700081,Orkun,TANER,CME2204,3,95,88,70,86,100,75,BA,Successful
2015700081,Orkun,TANER,CME2206,3,100,100,98,98,80,100,AA,Successful
2016700052,Ceren,ÖZTÜRK,CME3004,4,50,0,65,40,,45,DC,Failed
2015700085,Tarık,BABAOĞLU,CME2202,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,D,Absent
```

output xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<studentInfo>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700001</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Mesut</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>GAVGA</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>68</MID1>
    <MID2>74</MID2>
    <HW1>80</HW1>
    <HW2>75</HW2>
    <HW3>65</HW3>
    <FINAL>70</FINAL>
    <GRADE>CB</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700001</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Mesut</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>GAVGA</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3004</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>36</MID1>
    <MID2>32</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>0</HW2>
    <HW3>00</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700001</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Mesut</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>GAVGA</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>80</MID1>
    <MID2>75</MID2>
    <HW1>85</HW1>
    <HW2>78</HW2>
    <HW3>70</HW3>
    <FINAL>82</FINAL>
    <GRADE>BB</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700001</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Mesut</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>GAVGA</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>90</MID1>
    <MID2>90</MID2>
    <HW1>100</HW1>
    <HW2>96</HW2>
    <HW3>88</HW3>
    <FINAL>85</FINAL>
    <GRADE>AA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700018</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Merve Rana</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SARI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>0</MID1>
    <MID2>0</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>0</HW2>
    <HW3>0</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
    <GRADE>D</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Absent&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700018</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Merve Rana</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SARI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>55</MID1>
    <MID2>57</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>66</HW2>
    <HW3>60</HW3>
    <FINAL>48</FINAL>
    <GRADE>DC</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700018</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Merve Rana</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SARI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>60</MID1>
    <MID2>65</MID2>
    <HW1>70</HW1>
    <HW2>70</HW2>
    <HW3>63</HW3>
    <FINAL>60</FINAL>
    <GRADE>CC</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700022</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Nadir</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ÖZCAN</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>98</MID1>
    <MID2>95</MID2>
    <HW1>98</HW1>
    <HW2>90</HW2>
    <HW3>92</HW3>
    <FINAL>85</FINAL>
    <GRADE>AA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700022</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Nadir</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ÖZCAN</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3004</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>85</MID1>
    <MID2>90</MID2>
    <HW1>88</HW1>
    <HW2>90</HW2>
    <HW3>00</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700022</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Nadir</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ÖZCAN</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>90</MID1>
    <MID2>78</MID2>
    <HW1>95</HW1>
    <HW2>90</HW2>
    <HW3>88</HW3>
    <FINAL>92</FINAL>
    <GRADE>AA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700019</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Mehmet Emin</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>TATLI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>20</MID1>
    <MID2>12</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>25</HW2>
    <HW3>0</HW3>
    <FINAL>30</FINAL>
    <GRADE>FF</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Failed&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700019</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Mehmet Emin</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>TATLI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>15</MID1>
    <MID2>0</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>0</HW2>
    <HW3>0</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
    <GRADE>D</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Absent&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700030</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Ali</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SALMANLI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>82</MID1>
    <MID2>77</MID2>
    <HW1>100</HW1>
    <HW2>98</HW2>
    <HW3>100</HW3>
    <FINAL>68</FINAL>
    <GRADE>BA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700030</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Ali</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SALMANLI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3004</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>76</MID1>
    <MID2>80</MID2>
    <HW1>80</HW1>
    <HW2>80</HW2>
    <HW3>00</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700030</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Ali</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SALMANLI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3006</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>80</MID1>
    <MID2>00</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700030</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Ali</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>SALMANLI</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>90</MID1>
    <MID2>94</MID2>
    <HW1>95</HW1>
    <HW2>90</HW2>
    <HW3>88</HW3>
    <FINAL>80</FINAL>
    <GRADE>AA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700031</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Selin</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>BAYTUR</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>40</MID1>
    <MID2>38</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>20</HW2>
    <HW3>25</HW3>
    <FINAL>26</FINAL>
    <GRADE>FF</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Failed&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700031</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Selin</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>BAYTUR</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3004</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>65</MID1>
    <MID2>60</MID2>
    <HW1>72</HW1>
    <HW2>65</HW2>
    <HW3>00</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700031</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Selin</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>BAYTUR</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>60</MID1>
    <MID2>48</MID2>
    <HW1>50</HW1>
    <HW2>52</HW2>
    <HW3>50</HW3>
    <FINAL>60</FINAL>
    <GRADE>DC</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700020</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Oğulcan</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ÖZARSLAN</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>65</MID1>
    <MID2>80</MID2>
    <HW1>100</HW1>
    <HW2>100</HW2>
    <HW3>95</HW3>
    <FINAL>85</FINAL>
    <GRADE>BA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700020</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Oğulcan</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ÖZARSLAN</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>86</MID1>
    <MID2>88</MID2>
    <HW1>90</HW1>
    <HW2>90</HW2>
    <HW3>100</HW3>
    <FINAL>100</FINAL>
    <GRADE>AA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700042</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Murat</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>GÜREL</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>40</MID1>
    <MID2>0</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>50</HW2>
    <HW3>20</HW3>
    <FINAL>38</FINAL>
    <GRADE>FF</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Failed&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700042</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Murat</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>GÜREL</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>71</MID1>
    <MID2>63</MID2>
    <HW1>65</HW1>
    <HW2>74</HW2>
    <HW3>70</HW3>
    <FINAL>60</FINAL>
    <GRADE>CB</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700035</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Sercan</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ERGÖRMÜŞ</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3006</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>100</MID1>
    <MID2>00</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700036</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Çağla</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>PAK</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3006</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>47</MID1>
    <MID2>00</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700036</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Çağla</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>PAK</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>0</MID1>
    <MID2>0</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>0</HW2>
    <HW3>0</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
    <GRADE>D</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Absent&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700036</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Çağla</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>PAK</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>8</MID1>
    <MID2>18</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>25</HW2>
    <HW3>50</HW3>
    <FINAL>35</FINAL>
    <GRADE>FF</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Failed&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700037</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Kerim</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>KENAR</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>70</MID1>
    <MID2>75</MID2>
    <HW1>80</HW1>
    <HW2>80</HW2>
    <HW3>72</HW3>
    <FINAL>75</FINAL>
    <GRADE>BB</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700037</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Kerim</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>KENAR</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>80</MID1>
    <MID2>80</MID2>
    <HW1>85</HW1>
    <HW2>56</HW2>
    <HW3>70</HW3>
    <FINAL>48</FINAL>
    <GRADE>CB</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700050</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Eda</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>CANSEVER</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3006</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>45</MID1>
    <MID2>00</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700081</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Orkun</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>TANER</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2204</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>95</MID1>
    <MID2>88</MID2>
    <HW1>70</HW1>
    <HW2>86</HW2>
    <HW3>100</HW3>
    <FINAL>75</FINAL>
    <GRADE>BA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700081</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Orkun</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>TANER</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2206</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>100</MID1>
    <MID2>100</MID2>
    <HW1>98</HW1>
    <HW2>98</HW2>
    <HW3>80</HW3>
    <FINAL>100</FINAL>
    <GRADE>AA</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Successful&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2016700052</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Ceren</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>ÖZTÜRK</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME3004</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>4</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>50</MID1>
    <MID2>0</MID2>
    <HW1>65</HW1>
    <HW2>40</HW2>
    <HW3>00</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
  </students>
  <students>
    <STUDENT ID>2015700085</STUDENT ID>
    <STUDENT NAME>Tarık</STUDENT NAME>
    <STUDENT SURNAME>BABAOĞLU</STUDENT SURNAME>
    <COURSE CODE>CME2202</COURSE CODE>
    <COURSE CREDIT>3</COURSE CREDIT>
    <MID1>0</MID1>
    <MID2>0</MID2>
    <HW1>0</HW1>
    <HW2>0</HW2>
    <HW3>0</HW3>
    <FINAL>0</FINAL>
    <GRADE>D</GRADE>
    <STATUS
>Absent&#13;</STATUS
>
  </students>
</studentInfo>
```

C source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    xmlNodePtr root = NULL, node = NULL;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlDtdPtr dtd;

    doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST "1.0");
    root = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "studentInfo");
    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);

    FILE *freadptr;
    FILE *fwriteptr;
    char* token;
    char* token2;
    char* line;
    char* tags[13];
    char* texts[13];
    char buf1[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char buf2[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    freadptr = fopen("input.csv", "r");
    fwriteptr = fopen("ödev.xml", "w");

    if(freadptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error reading file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fgets(buf1, BUFFER_SIZE, freadptr);
    //printf("%s", buf1);
    token = strtok(buf1, ",\n");
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        //printf("%s|", token);
        tags[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
        i++;
    }

    while(fgets(buf2, BUFFER_SIZE, freadptr))
    {
        char* field;
        i = 0;
        line = buf2;
        //token2 = strsep(&line, ",\n");
        while((field = strsep(&line, ",\n")) != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(field, "") == 0)
            {
                //token2 = "0";
                strcpy(field, "0");
            }
            //printf("field=%s||", field);
            texts[i] = field;
            i++;
        }

        j = 0;
        node = xmlNewChild(root, NULL, BAD_CAST "students", BAD_CAST NULL);
        for(j = 0;j < i;j++)
        {
            xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST tags[j], BAD_CAST texts[j]);
            //printf("%s", texts[j]);
        }
    }

    xmlSaveFormatFileEnc("ödev.xml", doc, "UTF-8", 1);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    xmlMemoryDump();
    fclose(freadptr);
    fclose(fwriteptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consistency is key in programming. If you type `FILE *x` and `char* y` you are being inconsistent. You have to use one of both, and of course the correct one that doesn't lead to confusion ever, i.e. `TYPE *variable;`.

Comment: Ok, now to your question: Explain these, "*I cannot see some csv columns in xml file.*"? and you don't really need libxml for such a simple case, and although it ensures correctness, it's not really needed and it actually adds a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) That "funny" character is a `\r` which is part of the end of line marker (along with `\n`) in your file. Probably easiest to add it to the list of things you're splitting the line on.

2) That is most likely because some of the headings generate invalid tags, ie "STUDENT ID". You can't have a space in a tag name - you should go through each string in `tags` and replace all white space and other invalid characters with an underscore or just remove them.

3) `strsep` isn't creating new strings, it's just taking `buf2` and returning different pointers inside it. So you can't `strcpy` into it. Instead move the check into the XML creation and just do

```
xmlNewChild(node, NULL, BAD_CAST tags[j], BAD_CAST "0");
```